# NotImplementedError for Importing Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm attempting to import a Jupyter Notebook into Python. I created a file called NotebookImport.py following the instructions here: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html. I then created a file called ImportTest.py with this code at the start:

```
import NotebookImport
import ml.HTML_Only.ipynb
```

Anytime I try to run this module, it starts importing the Jupyter Notebook, but I get this error:

```
NotImplementedError: Implement enable_gui in a subclass
```

Any idea how to fix this?
In case this matters, I'm using Anaconda Prompt to run this, inside a conda virtual environment.